# How to make a plan in an endgame?

Tags: strategy, endgame

I need help on how to improve my thinking about endgames and how to produce a plan, what should I focus on and what should I not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Planning in the endgame (this is what I seek on endgames)

Here is a breakdown of the different imbalances and what you should aim for:

1. Material (owning pieces of greater value than the opponent's);
2. Space (the annexation of territory on a chess board);
3. Superior Minor Piece (the interplay between Bishops and Knights);
4. Pawn Structure (a broad subject that encompasses doubled pawns,
   isolated pawns, etc.);
5. Control of a key file or square (files and diagonals act as pathways
   for your pieces, while squares act as outposts);
6. Lead in development (more force in a specific area of the board);
7. Initiative (dictating the tempo of a game).

If we are to use these things properly we must be able to break down our thinking in a way that allows us to dissect any particular position.

Here are the stages of my thinking technique that enables us to accomplish this:

1. Figure out the positive and negative imbalances for both sides;
2. Figure out the side of the board you wish to play on. You can only
   play where a favorable imbalance or the possibility of creating a
   favorable imbalance exists;
3. Don't calculate! Instead, dream up various fantasy positions, i.e.,
   the positions you would most like to achieve;
4. Once you find a fantasy position that makes you happy, you must
   figure out if you can reach it. If you find that your choice was not
   possible to achieve, you must create another dream position easier
   to achieve;
5. Only now you will look at the moves you wish to calculate (called
   candidate moves). The candidate moves are all the moves that lead to
   our dream position.